# regex to match based on number or condition specified

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I need help with one situation.

I have a file with list of strings/ urls where I have to make furthur processing.

e.g.
I have a string like below:

> GET /customers/47018485/communicationPreferences/channels/email/marketingEnabled?categories=superman&activeConsent=true&param1=qqq&param2=qwsa

Now I wrote a regex to filter params like:

```
&([^=]*)
```

[image: output by regexer]

I am able to successfully filter/match params:

activeConsent | param1 | param2

Now, further in my regex, I want some modification where I just specify the number of the match to use like
if I want only param1 output I just specify something like -----   `&([^=]*)[2]` or if I want to param2, I just specify `&([^=]*)[3]`, etc.
I know we cannot give 1,2,3... etc but I just need a way to further process output obtained by regex with another regex.

Comment: Use `^.*?(?:&[^=]*.*?){n-1}&([^=]*)` where `n` is the number of the match.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? Why can't you match all params, then select the one you need in your host languange (Java, C#, JavaScript, PHP, Python, …)?

Comment: Hi @41686d6564 , I tried -- ^.*?(?:&[^=]*.*?){n-1}&([^=]*) but its not working as expected. When I use this it hilights all previous string other than param where in {n-1} i put number like {1} or {2} etc.  Also please see that my whole goal is to get exactly parameter name as param1 , param2 etc. based on n value I provide . Also the name of parameters might differ and the count of parameters will also differer like I might have a string in future which has 10 paranmeters like param1, param2, param3 .... and so on .... Thanks

Comment: @smith What regex flavor (or programming language) are you using? And what _exactly_ do you mean by _"not working as expected"_? I'm assuming you didn't actually use `^.*?(?:&[^=]*.*?){n-1}&([^=]*)` _as is_ and that you replaced `n-1` with a number, right?

Comment: Hi @41686d6564 edited my comment above . also I am not using any programming language . I have a tool which takes regex as input. U can take example of notepad where I have all the strings. Use case is ... I open that file put regex and put n value and all the params are searched then I copy them and use them else where.

Comment: Hi @knittl given the situation I cant use any programing language . It would have been easier with programming lanaguage but I have to put regex in a tool which is used in my organization

Comment: @smith What's the name of the tool that you're using or what regex flavor does it support? Re: _"it hilights all previous string other than param"_ Well, the param is in the capturing group. I thought that's obvious because you were using a capturing group with your original pattern (notice how `&` is part of the match but not part of the group capture?)

Comment: @41686d6564 name of tool Repeater , its developed by my organization itself. Regex flavour it supports : PCRE

Comment: ``(?>.*?&\K[^=]+){n}``

Comment: Hi @Michail suppose I use Java8 regex flavour then in that case \K wont work . Now suppose I have a regex : as (?<==)(.*?)((?=&)|(?=\s))  , it matches all the parameter values now how to match nth match in that case.

Comment: ``(?>.*?&([^=]+)){n}`` let you get result in goup1

Comment: Hi @Michail , I tried with your regex but selects value from starting , but I need help with matching only value of parameter based on {n} value . Please see screenshot in link : https://ibb.co/6gYYw0G

Comment: Result is in capture group 1

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^.*?(?:&[^=]+.*?){n-1}&\K[^=]+
```

...where `n` is the number of the param you're looking for.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dpwQEo/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of string.
- `.*?` - Match one or more characters (as few as possible).
- `(?:` - Start a non-capturing group.

  - `&[^=]+` - Match '&' followed by one or more characters other than '='.
  - `.*?` - Match one or more characters (as few as possible).
- `)` - End of non-capturing group.
- `{n-1}` - Match the previous group a number of `n-1` times.
- `\K` - Reset the starting point of the match (i.e., only include what comes next).
- `[^=]+` - Match '&' followed by one or more characters other than '='.

Note: you probably should assert that each param name is immediately followed by `=`. In which case, you may modify the pattern above to become:

```regex
^.*?(?:&[^=]+=.*?){1}&\K[^=]+(?==)
#            ^               ^^^^^
```